# Uncaught ReferenceError: LoadFile is not defined Error

Tags: javascript, html

When I run this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Upload Button</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" style="display:none" onchange="LoadFile(event)" id="file" name="image"/>
    <label for="file" style="cursor:pointer">Upload image</label>
    <br>
    <img id="output" style="width:200px; height:200px;"/>
    <script>
      var loadFile = function(event) {
     var image = document.getElementById("output");
  image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
   };
 </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The browser throws this error:

> `Uncaught ReferenceError: LoadFile is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onchange (tp1.html:7)`

It says that function `LoadFile()` isn't defined and I found this strange because the function is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript is case-sensitive. You should call `loadFile()` instead of `LoadFile()` in `onchange`.
Here's your code:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Upload Button</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" style="display:none;" onchange="loadFile(event)" id="file" name="image"/>
    <label for="file" style="cursor:pointer">Upload image</label>
    <br>
    <img id="output" style="width:200px; height:200px;"/>
    <script>
            var loadFile = function(event) {
            var image = document.getElementById("output");
            image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
            };
        </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Or change `loadFile()` to `LaodFile()`:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Upload Button</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" style="display:none;" onchange="LoadFile(event)" id="file" name="image"/>
    <label for="file" style="cursor:pointer">Upload image</label>
    <br>
    <img id="output" style="width:200px; height:200px;"/>
    <script>
            var LoadFile = function(event) {
            var image = document.getElementById("output");
            image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
            };
        </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you declared is "loadFile", but you use "LoadFile" in onchange.